# In TypeScript, why isn't my type resolving correctly?

Tags: typescript

My code is as follows:

```
class MyFile {

    fileName: string;
    checksum: string;

    constructor(fileName: string, checksum: string) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.checksum = checksum;
    }
}

async function getFile() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(new MyFile("test.pdf", "abcdefgh"));
    });
}

async function run() {
    const file = await getFile();
    const fileName = file.fileName;
}
```

I get the following compile error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'fileName' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Why isn't my MyFile type being correctly detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not assigning the `MyFile` type to the `file` variable, so the static analyzer is not aware of the properties on it.  One you assign the `MyFile` type to `file` you need to add the `MyFile` type to the `Promise` returned by your `getFile` function.

```
class MyFile {

    fileName: string;
    checksum: string;

    constructor(fileName: string, checksum: string) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.checksum = checksum;
    }
}

async function getFile(): Promise<MyFile> {
    return new Promise<MyFile>(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(new MyFile("test.pdf", "abcdefgh"));
    });
}

async function run() {
    const file: MyFile = await getFile();
    const fileName: string = file.fileName;
}
```

Comment: It's enough to only specify promise generic type (`new Promise<MyFile>`). Function's return type and variable's type will be inferred automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In this case generic type (promise resolve type) can't be inferred from parameter types. You can hint the compiler by specifying it explicitly:

```
return new Promise<MyFile>((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
});
```

Other option is using `Promise.resolve` shortcut:

```
return Promise.resolve(new MyFile("test.pdf", "abcdefgh"));
```